# How to schedule cron sending message to ActiveMQ broker using Golang?

Tags: go, cron, activemq-classic

I am using Golang. I want to send message (scheduled with cron) to ActiveMQ Broker like this [document](https://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery) (`AMQ_SCHEDULED_CRON`)

When looking up this [document](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-stomp/stomp/v3#section-readme). I did not find anything mentioning about schedule sending cron message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a message to be scheduled just send it with the appropriate property. If you're using STOMP message properties are set as headers on the [`MESSAGE` frame](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#MESSAGE).